# How can I update the position of my marker (from SQL database) without reloading the page, or refreshing the map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am producing a Google API map where the latitude and longitude positions are being created/read in from an SQL database hosted on PHPMyAdmin.

Each time my GPS module gets a fix, the old location is deleted, and the new location uploaded to the database.

I need the position of my marker to 'move' based on location within the database. This will change with each new 'fix'.

I looked at other threads, some suggest using a  refresh tag to reload the page. Others suggest using a

```
 setInterval
```

function (still in code) to reload the map. These work - however, they produce an unwanted flicker and means the map is unusable in fullscreen mode. It also means that if I wanted to explore the map, I am refreshed to the marker location every 5 seconds.

Instead, I want only the marker to be refreshed/reloaded so it 'moves'. I have seen one answer use AJAX - but I am a beginner, and don't have the background understanding of what AJAX is and how to apply it to my code.

Here is my code:

```js
function initMap() {

/***************************************************************************/
//Creates own marker image for map
  var ReferencePos = {lat: 52.948616, lng: -1.169131};
  /*************************************************** 
************************/

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  //center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.948616, -1.169131),
  center: ReferencePos,
  zoom: 19
  });
               
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
  //downloadUrl('https://storage.googleapis.com/mapsdevsite/json/mapmarkers2.xml', function(data) {

  downloadUrl('http://localhost/projectgmaps/map_xml_cycle.php', function(data) {

    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');

    //Stores the data from the database into an array 
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem, idx) {
      var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
      var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
      var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
      var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
        parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

      //Creates the content windows 
      var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
      var strong = document.createElement('strong');

      strong.textContent = name
      infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
      infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

      var text = document.createElement('text');
      text.textContent = address
      infowincontent.appendChild(text);
      var icon = customLabel[type] || {};

      //Creates new marker
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label,
        center: point,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/cycling.png'
      });
            
      var reference = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: ReferencePos,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png',
        label: 'R'
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });

/*************************************************************************************************/
//Centres map on marker
      if (idx == 0) // first marker, center the map on its position
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
/*************************************************************************************************/

    });
  });
}

/*************************************************************************************************/
//Refreshes map every 5 seconds so marker updates
setInterval ( function(){
  initMap();
},5000);
/*************************************************************************************************/

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
  new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
  new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

Note - I have looked at every thread on here that I could find relating to my issue, but most were slightly different, or very confusing answers, so I'm looking for a very clear cut answer to append to my code

Cheers!

Comment: The only way to do what you're looking for is with push notifications from the server.  I'd recommend having a look at sockets... http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Answer (score 1):

Once you've the positions, you can easily reuse the `marker` object to set positions without refreshing the entire map.

Like:

```
marker.setPosition({lat: 12.3456, lng: 12.3456}); // Sets the marker to new position  
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); // If you want to center the map to the new position
```

Now, for the periodic refreshing, I'd suggest you to look at [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)